# If cell A2 contains certain text put specific value in a cell B2

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out the way to enter the value into cell `B2` when the specific value is picked from the drop down list in `A2` cell. For example I pick a `HOTEL` from `A2` drop down and it gives me a `800` value in `B2` cell. And so on - another value picked from drop down, another value entered in `B2` cell.

So far I managed to get it right for one item (`HOTEL`). This condition works correctly however I struggle to add more values there for another items (`TAXI`, `TRain`, etc). Should I add `AND` or `OR` somewhere?

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("hotel",A5)),800,0)
```

I have tried the following however unsuccessfully:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("hotel",A5)),800,0),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("taxi",A5)),8000,0)
```

Comment: Set up a table, and use `VLOOKUP`.

Comment: start basic:  enter formula `=A2` somewhere, then pick something rrom the dropdown. whats A2? a number or a word?

Comment: It is a text, what I have is HOTEL, TAXI, TRAIN. Each one picked from list should provide different value in B2. Value to be specified in IF condition settings

Answer (score 1):

Use a nested IF statement, or a VLOOKUP.

Assuming you have a Data Validation list in Cell A2, for nested IF - in B2 enter:

=IF(A2="Hotel",800,IF(A2="Train",500,IF(A2="Taxi",8000,"Please select item from dropdown")))

Extend this to match your drop down options.

For VLOOKUP:

Add a table elsewhere in your workbook with the drop down values in the first column and lookup values in the second column:

Hotel | 800

Train | 500

Taxi | 8000

Name these cells/columns as a range, say 'mylookup'.

In B2:

=VLOOKUP(A2,mylookup,2,FALSE)

Answer (score 1):

Use a switch statement

```
=SWITCH(A5,”HOTEL”,800,”TRAIN”,500,”TAXI”,8000)
```

Comment: The SWITCH function is new in Excel 2016 on Windows, and won't work in other versions of Excel. It's not yet available in Mac Excel 2016.